# JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty 'expression'. TS17000

Tags: reactjs, typescript

At minimum, the style prop below will always have a margin property. But I guess potentially spreading `undefined` is still an issue?

If so, what is the best way to fix this?

```
interface PropsShape {
  maxContainerWidth: string,
  imageSrc: string,
  imageAlt: string,
  style?: object
}

export default (props: PropsShape) => (
  <Container 
    maxContainerWidth={props.maxContainerWidth} 
    style={{
      ...props.style, // JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty 'expression'.  TS17000
      margin: '0 auto'
    }}
  >
    <FittedImage src={props.imageSrc} alt={props.imageAlt} />
  </Container>
)

const Container = styled.div<Pick<PropsShape, 'maxContainerWidth'>>`
  max-width: ${props => props.maxContainerWidth};
`
```

Comment: I think you can add `style?: any` instead of this **style?: object**. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @JayParmar this did fix it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript compiler seemed to think an empty object was passed. Including `undefined` in the type definition fixed this issue:

```
interface PropsShape {
  maxContainerWidth: string,
  imageSrc: string,
  imageAlt: string,
  style?: object | undefined
}
`
```